# How to store SQL select to gridview using ASP.net C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [order] WHERE date>=@begin AND date<=@end", con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@begin",dt1);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", dt2);
```

This is my select statement. I want to put the result to data gridview. How to use dataset to store in gridview in asp.net C#?

Answer (score 6):

Use a [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx).

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [order] WHERE date>=@begin AND date<=@end", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@begin",dt1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", dt2);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapater(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
yourGridView.DataSource = dt;
yourGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: do i have to put the command in sql adapter like this
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapater(cmd);

Comment: @ReynanCapco s u have to include your command and connectionstring in SqlDataAdapter..

Comment: @coder no you don't, if it is in the `SqlCommand` as stated, you don't have to.

Comment: @LukeHennerley without passing the sqlcommand how will u get the value and fill it in the adapter..

Comment: @coder I am not saying that we don't pass the `SqlCommand`, I am saying we don't need to pass `SqlCommand` and the `Connection`. Read the current code.

Comment: @LukeHennerley yeah we can pass only the sqlcommands object like cmd in the above case.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `SqlDataReader` object to execute your command and a `DataTable` to load the results into the GridView:

```
   SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Load(dr);

   gv.DataSource = dt;
   gv.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);

        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        oda.Fill(ds);
```

here assign datasource to gridview

```
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

and don't forget to write this piece of code

```
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: where did you use your datatable?

Answer (score 2):

You can use with [`SqlDataAdaper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx)

> Represents a set of data commands and a database connection that are
>   used to fill the DataSet and update a SQL Server database.

with [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

> Represents one table of in-memory data.

with [`Gridview.DataBind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method

> Binds the data source to the GridView control.

as

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapater(cmd, conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SQLDataAdapter` to do this..

```
SqlDataAdapter adp=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
Datatable dt=new Datatable();
adp.fill(dt);
gridview.Datasource=dt;
gridview.Databind();
```