# Resolve Value from Table to Another Table using an ID

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, gridview

I want to use data from Helpers (HelperID) to resolve data from Users (FirstName).

So my pseudo-code would look *like*:

**Tables:**

**[Users]**

Id FirstName

0 Brandon

1 Stephen

2 Jon

3 Eric

4 Kyle

5 Stan

**[Helpers]**

Id HelperID

0 1

1 3

2 4

3 5

> SELECT ID, FirstName FROM [Users] WHERE ID == [Helpers].HelperID

**Output:**
Stephen
Eric
Kyle
Stan

That's all I want. How is this possible? Seems like such an easy task but is becoming a real pain.

How can it be implemented into Visual Studio ASP.NET C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to add the second table to your `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT [Users].ID, [Users].FirstName
FROM [Users], [Helpers]
WHERE [Users].ID == [Helpers].HelperID
```

Or use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT [Users].ID, [Users].FirstName
FROM [Users] 
INNER JOIN [Helpers]
    ON [Users].ID = [Helpers].HelperID
```

Comment: How do I implement it into Visual Studio ASP.NET C# using a GridView to list out the Helpers with their names?

Comment: That's a very broad question for a comment. Ask a new question and show what you have so far.

Comment: It was a broad question. I figured it out and this definitely helped me. Thanks! (Solved)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT FirstName FROM Helpers JOIN Users on Helpers.HelperID=Users.Id

Comment: Right... That's good but how do I put that into Visual Studio using C# with GridViews and SqlDataSources.

Comment: @BrandonMXB There are innumerable tutorials for reading data from SQL in C# and displaying the results in GridViews on the web. Please give it a shot and tell us exactly where you get stuck in the process. We're not here to write code for you, we're here to help you with specific questions. You now have answers for the question you presented here. If you have other questions regarding data sources and GridViews, please create a new question about those specific problems.

Comment: I understand that. I didn't wanna flood my OP with what I've done so far, so when this is looked up by others, they're not encumbered but I have obviously looked everywhere. There's a mixture of people attempting different things programmatically and then some using the build in GUI tools. I've attempted using a 2 GridViews and going through each value, but that's just way too much for a simple SQL statement. I didn't know if there's an easier more efficient way  of doing this.

Comment: The top answer on this question gives you a very simple way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546017/how-to-store-sql-select-to-gridview-asp-net-c-sharp You don't have parameters in your query, so you can ignore the 2 lines of code that add the parameters. You'll have to open a `SqlConnection` first, but documentation on that is readily available on the MSDN site and other places.